# How to run “sudo apt-get update” through proxy in commandline?

Tags: linux, networking, proxy

In my office I want to update and download through `wget` and here they are using a proxy. How can I get `wget` to use the proxy from the command-line?

Comment: The title references `apt-get` but the question is about `wget`.  Which one of the two are you interested in?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/7470/67621

Answer (score 5):

Either export the `http_proxy` environment variable as in `export http_proxy=http://myproxy:port` or add

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://MYNAME:MYPASS@MY.PROXY.COM:MYPORT"
```

To `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=96802

Comment: Acquire::http::Proxy "http://MYDOMAIN\MYNAME:MYPASS@MY.PROXY.COM:MYPORT"   correct?

Comment: Don't know, depends on your proxy and how it works.

Comment: :-( , I am getting error "Access to web proxy service denied!"

Answer (score 0):

If your machine is behind a proxy running a Microsoft NTLM based web proxy you may need something like the (python based) [ntlmaps](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/) to sit between wget/apt-get and the real proxy to do the authentication for you.